# webkit animation props

Tags: css, html, webkit

is there a way to get a webkit animation to run indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There certainly **is**:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
}

img.pulse { opacity: 0.75; }
img.pulse:hover { 
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10; 
}
```

This was taken from the [source, here](http://www.zurb.com/article/221/css3-animation-will-rock-your-world)

The important parts to observe (obviously, I suppose) are those within the `keyframes` `@-webkit-keyframes pulse {/*...*/}`, defining the animation's name 'pulse' the `from` (start), 50% mark, and `to` (end) (which you'll notice is exactly the same as the `from` declaration, to give the impression of seamless animation.

On second thoughts, it seems that `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10;` might present a problem, as regards 'infinite.' Omitting this property means the animation occurs once, setting the value to `0` (as expected) prevents the animation occurring at all.

So, perhaps not infinite, but it seems happy with a value of `3000`, so presumably other similarly-large numbers would be do-able.

Revised demo [with super-large `-webkit-animation-iteration-count` of over nine-thousaaaaaand...](http://jsbin.com/eleti3/4/)

---

**Edited** in surprise:

Apparently `infinite` *is*, in fact, a [valid argument](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-animation-iteration-count) for the `-webkit-animation-iteration-count`. See the *newest* demo, at [jsbin (again)](http://jsbin.com/eleti3/5/).

Comment: @hvgotcodes, it is a bit, isn't it? But then, what do I know? I'm still flabbergasted that `:first-word` isn't a valid pseudo-selector (to join `:first-line` and `:first-letter`)...

Comment: @hvgotcodes, see the latest edit, up there. `infinite` **is** allowed as a value. =)

Comment: The only link I have to support it is the one that's towards the bottom of my answer (with the link text of 'valid argument,' I'm afraid.